# Convincing Perltidy to leave whitespace alone

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

I am using [Perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) to reformat a few of my old Perl files to a style that is closer to my current preferences. I encountered an issue with this snippet:

```
Fcntl::S_IRUSR & $mode
```

Perltidy *insists* on removing the space after the `&` token, resulting into this:

```
Fcntl::S_IRUSR &$mode
```

...which in my opinion is an eyesore. What can I do to convince Perltidy to leave that single space alone? I even tried the `-fws` option to no avail.

I am using Perltidy 20101217, which is apparently the latest version.

EDIT:

A few additional observations:

- Using the `--indent-only` (`-io`) option does not remove the aforementioned space.
- The following equivalent snippet is not affected by this issue:

  ```
  $mode & Fcntl::S_IRUSR
  ```

EDIT 2:

I ended up reversing the order of the `&` operator arguments, since that seems to work around the Perltidy issue for the time being. In addition this approach does not require adding extra parentheses or any other tokens that *might* help Perltidy do The Right Thing, but would *certainly* confuse *me* in the long run.

UPDATE:

I contacted Steve Hancock, the author of Perltidy, about this issue. From his response:

> I checked and the problem is that the & is being mistokenized in this
>   case as a function call sigil. The basic problem is that perltidy
>   does not see prototypes for other modules, even built-in, so it has to
>   guess when it comes to something like "Fcntl::S_IRUSR". In other
>   words, it doesn't know if this is a function call or a constant, and
>   has to guess. When you reversed the order it removed the ambiguity on
>   the &.
>
> Thanks for the note. I'll see if I can come up with a patch to fix
>   this.

Comment: Looks like perltidy is misinterpreting `&` as the function sigil instead of the bitwise-and operator?

Comment: @mob: that's what I thought too. However, I still find the lack of respect towards `-fws` disturbing...

Comment: @MisterEd: Yes, `--indent-only` does work, but it is not enough for what I want to do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It surely incorrectly thinks

```
Fcntl::S_IRUSR & $mode
```

means

```
Fcntl::S_IRUSR(&$mode)
```

You can probably trick it by using

```
(Fcntl::S_IRUSR) & $mode
```

or

```
Fcntl::S_IRUSR() & $mode
```

Comment: I ended up just reversing the `&` operator arguments, since that does not require any extra tokens in the code that might confuse me later on (see my edit).